# Css scale elements and force container element to collapse to the appropriate size

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a list of inline-blocks that are arranged side-by-side with `white-space: nowrap`. These elements should stretch off the screen and be scrollable with a `overflow-x: scroll`.

The caveat is that the contents of those inline blocks contain elements that are scaled down. This works great except the list items themselves do not scale down and therefore the scrollbar is too far down. It would make sense if I just scaled the list itself but the list items contain some items that are NOT supposed to be scaled.

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <span>ABC</span>
        <div class="scale">
            <div class="big-block"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>ABC</span>
        <div class="scale">
            <div class="big-block"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
            ...
```

[Here is a reduced test case demonstrating the issue.](http://jsbin.com/OnAZIzo/4/edit?html,css,output).

I have attempted to do this with floats instead of `white-space: nowrap` and I got the scrollbar to position correctly (I *think* maybe because the elements were removed from the document flow) but the floats would wrap unless I put a high width on the container. This would work on chrome but cause an obnoxiously long scrollbar on firefox which was not dependent on the container contents.

How do I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Ideas that "could" work (but don't): padding-right: -50%;  but padding can not be negative. margin-right: -50% but negative margins have bad support ...

Comment: @vals negative margin support is fine but if you apply it to the container it moves everything up. And 50% seems completely arbitrary - the scaling might change as well.

Answer (score 1):

the webkit transform doesnt resize the dom elements for the document to flow properly - you'd have to use some javascript on the parent container to get round it..

```
var scaleFactor = 0.5;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('scale');
for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
  // noprotect

  elements[i].style.width = (elements[i].offsetWidth * scaleFactor) + 'px';
  elements[i].style.height = (elements[i].offsetHeight * scaleFactor) + 'px';

}
```

http://jsbin.com/OnAZIzo/9/

Comment: The problem with this is that there's no good event to tie into to determine when to do this. I can of course do this in javascript in a dozen different ways, everything from floating and resizing the container to positioning everything absolutely, unfortunately any of these approaches require a lot of work and are not too precise. I feel like there must be a css way of doing this, just something that I am missing.